How to call API that needs Microsoft login in php?
when I try to call an API that need Microsoft Login using php
$client_id = 'a38fdcab-8ebf-4cde-a3fe-001d40caa289'; // replace with your client id
$client_secret = 'xxx'; // replace with your client secret
$resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'; // replace with your resource
$username = 'xxx'; // replace with your username
$password = 'xxx'; // replace with your password
$redirect_uri = 'xxx';

$authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1a5384f-f0fc-4df9-9f37-caf775af43c1';

$params = array(
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'resource' => $resource,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read openid email profile',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
);

json_encode($params);
$curl = new curl();
$curl->setopt(array(
    'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false,
    'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST' => false,
));

$tokenUrl = $authority . '/oauth2/token';
$result = $curl->post($tokenUrl, $params);



if ($curl->get_errno()) {
    throw new moodle_exception('Failed to get access token: ' . $curl->error);
}

$result = $curl->post($tokenUrl, $params);

if ($curl->get_errno()) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . $curl->error;
    exit;
}

if ($result === false) {
    echo 'No response from server';
    exit;
}

$tokenData = json_decode($result, true);

if (!isset($tokenData['access_token'])) {
    echo 'No access token in response: ' . $result;
    exit;
}


$tokenData = json_decode($result, true);
$accessToken = $tokenData['access_token'];
echo ($accessToken . "<br>");

echo 'user authenticated successfully'. "<br>";


$apiUrl = 'xxx';


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiUrl,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false, // don't follow redirects
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Accept: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // disable SSL verification
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, // disable SSL verification
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl) . "<br>";
    exit;
}

$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "HTTP status code: $httpStatusCode\n" . "<br>";

if ($httpStatusCode >= 300 && $httpStatusCode < 400) {
    $location = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    echo "Redirect URL: $location\n" . "<br>";
}



// echo "Raw response: $response\n";

var_dump($response);

$data = json_decode($response, true);


echo json_last_error() . "<br>";
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo 'JSON decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg() . "<br>";

}

var_dump($data);
curl_close($curl);

The response coming in is appending on my webpage parameter called cb and the page goes to infinite loop of refreshing and appending this parameter; however, the expected result is to get JSON response.
Do anyone know why is this happening?
